# Continuously starting a thread

Tags: c#, multithreading

I'm using c# to develop a program that takes a lot of bitmaps, divides them into pieces and sends them over UDP.

My problem here is, the Form freezes while I send frames continuously; this makes sense because the thread that the form is running on executes the send instruction during the time. In order to solve that, I'm trying to use a thread that is different from the one with the form, but when I use this:

```
Thread sender = new Thread(SendAFrame);

for(int c = 0; c < arrayList.Count; c++)
{
   Sender.Start();
}
```

I get an error because more than one of the thread is executed concurrently with this code. How can I solve this problem? Please keep in mind that using threading is not a must, an alternative solution is also greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you appear to be starting the same thread over and over again rather than spawning a new thread and starting the new thread

Comment: You have to look at ThreadPool Class: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.threadpool.aspx

Comment: did u try to send asynchronously

Comment: Post the code exists in the `Sender`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't start a thread for each "message". Start one threads that sends all messages. IOW move the loop into the thread.

Comment: I'd also recommend looking at using something a little higher level than `Thread`. TPL (`Task`) or `BackgroundWorker` would probably be an easier place to start.

Comment: I had to modify my code to do so, but I did that and it worked. Thanks for your advice. Simple is always better.

Answer (score 1):

You should start your send loop in the separate thread, you can use Task class to implement it.

```
var task = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => 
{
  for(int c = 0; c < arrayList.Count; c++)
  {
    SendAFrame(c);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `Join` method to find when your thread ends. After ending that thread `Start` another thread:

```
for(int c = 0; c < arrayList.Count; c++)
{
    Sender.Start();  
    Sender.Join();
}
```

Comment: That makes no sense. Why start a thread, then join it? No concurrency. This is a "shut up the error" fix that does not address the real problem.

Comment: @usr For every frame a thread will `Start` and after sending frame, new thread will `Start` for the new frame.

Comment: In between it will be blocked which is the point that makes no sense.

Answer (score 0):

you can do this to start a thread for each item in the list

```
for(int c = 0; c < arrayList.Count; c++)
{
   Thread thrd = new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(StratMe));
   thrd.Start(i);
}

 private void StratMe(object obj)
  {
     int i = (int) obj;
  }
```

or just one thread to do them all sequentially.

Comment: The same comment applies as I made with Shaharyar. Your solution gains nothing over using no threads at all due to the join.

Comment: This code will freze UI too